# Calculate total running processes and return value in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am looking for a small little Batch file that counts total running processes and returns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listing with `tasklist` and counting the .exe's with `find`

```
tasklist | find /i ".exe" /c
```

note that this excludes "System" and "System Idle Process" (are there more processes without an .exe?)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
tasklist | find /c "."
pause>nul
```